# Count total Sum from fetched API / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to calculate totalSum. Api gives 'amount' rows, but I need to add them together and cant yet find correct function. I am still learning with reactjs.

```
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/expense";
const TableCardList = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
        console.timeLog(data);
    };
    useEffect (() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    let tableList = data.map((row) => {
        return (
            <TableCard
            key={row.id}
            id={row.id}
            created_at={row.created_at}
            title={row.title}
            category={row.category}
            amount={row.amount}
            />
        );
    });

    return(
        <div className="row">
            <table class="table">
            {tableList}
            <td><b className="number"> {totalSum} Eur</b></td>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};
export default TableCardList;
```

Comment: use tableList.length

Comment: Use `data.length`

Comment: I understand that I need lenght of array, but I dont know how to formulate this function and where to place it. I spend way too much time on this...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.prototype.reduce can do the trick

```
const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/expense";
const TableCardList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [totalSum, setTotalSum] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
      console.timeLog(data);
    };
    getData()
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const total = data.reduce((acc, row) => acc + row.amount, 0);
    setTotalSum(total)
  }, [data]);

  let tableList = data.map((row) => (
    <TableCard
      key={row.id}
      id={row.id}
      created_at={row.created_at}
      title={row.title}
      category={row.category}
      amount={row.amount}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <table class="table">
        {tableList}
        <td><b className="number"> {totalSum} Eur</b></td>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableCardList;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is close but yet smth is missing. {totalSum}  outputs all of row.amount numbers inline but doesnt add them together. Output looks like this: 0221.56433.0033.00332.5542.00 Eur. I need to add them.

Comment: Maybe row.amount is in string format,  try to add parseFloat to `row.amount` like this `const total = data.reduce((acc, row) => acc + parseFloat(row.amount), 0);`

Comment: Sadly cant leave positive feedback. Thank you, works like a charm! I changed datatype to float because I needed to add cents as well. Bravo!

Comment: Why can't you give positive feedback?
you can still mark the question as answered to help others